# TypeError: clickButton() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a calculator in Python using Tkinter, and I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: clickButton() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'
```

Here's the code I've written:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")

ent = Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=5)
ent.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10) 


def clickButton(number):
    current = ent.get()
    ent.delete(0, END)
    ent.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))


def clearButton():
    ent.delete(0, END)


def button_add():
    first_number = ent.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "addition"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    ent.delete(0, END)


def equalButton():
    secondNum = ent.get()
    ent.delete(0,END)
    ent.insert(0, f_num + int(secondNum))


# this defines the buttons
button1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: clickButton(1)) # the first button of the calculator
button2 = Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: clickButton(2)) # the second button of the calculator
button3 = Button(root, text="3", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: clickButton(3)) # the third button of the calculator
button4 = Button(root, text="4", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: clickButton(4)) # the fourth button of the calculator
button5 = Button(root, text="5", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: clickButton(5)) # the fifth button of the calculator
button6 = Button(root, text="6", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: clickButton(6)) # the sixth  button of the calculator
button7 = Button(root, text="7", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: clickButton(7)) # the seventh button of the calculator
button8 = Button(root, text="8", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: clickButton(8)) # the eighth button of the calculator
button9 = Button(root, text="9", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: clickButton(9)) # the ninth button of the calculator
button0 = Button(root, text="0", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: clickButton(0)) # the tenth button of the calculator
button_addition = Button(root, text="+", padx=40, pady=20, command=clickButton) # addition button
button_equalSign = Button(root, text="=", padx=91, pady=20, command=equalButton) # button for the equal sign
button_clr = Button(root, text="C", padx=91, pady=20, command=lambda: clearButton()) #button for clearing whatever is written

# this puts the buttons on the screen

#row 3
button1.grid(row=3, column=0)
button2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button3.grid(row=3, column=2)

# row 2
button4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button6.grid(row=2, column=2)

# row 1
button7.grid(row=1, column=0)
button8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button9.grid(row=1, column=2)

# sign buttons
button0.grid(row=4, column=0)
button_clr.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)
button_addition.grid(row=5, column=0)
button_equalSign.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

I've been trying to fix this error for many hours.

P.S. I don't actually know which line the error is on, because it's saying that the error is on line 1705, even though the code is only 101 lines

Comment: please post the full error code, the line they mentioned the error on is the line of the module and not your script.

Comment: The line number shown in the error message is within the part of the `tkinter` module's code that handles callback (`command`) functions. The problem is because you're (apparently) trying to call the `clickButton()` function to handle the `+` or `=` `Button`s and not passing is the `number` argument it expects. Even if you fixed it to call the function, it still wouldn't do what you want because  `+` and `=` aren't digits like it expects `number` to be.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```py
button_addition = Button(root, text="+", padx=40, pady=20, command=clickButton) # addition button
```

You are calling `clickButton` with no arguments, and in your function, you are requiring a `number`. You should use `lambda`, as you did with the other numbers (lines above), or call another function. By the look of your code, it should be `button_add`.

Comment: However the fact that the argument is not a (single digit) number as `clickButton()` expects will likely be (another) problem.

Comment: Then, you should prepare your function clickButton() to accept "+" as an argument. And in that case you should still use lambda.

Comment: Glad it worked! In this case, feel free to mark this answer as correct, for future users :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it this way:

```
myButtonSum = Button(root, text="+", padx=10, pady=5, command=lambda: buttonAdd("+"))
```